# Swiper js not appearing until I refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, swiper.js

I'm experiencing a very frustrating bug with Swiper. I created my swiper in a modal ( just putting it out there ). Let's say I logout and login again and open the Modal, the swiper doesn't come up initially, until I refresh the page.
[image: Before refresh]

What could be causing this please?

[image: After refresh]

My imports

```
import { Modal, ModalOverlay, ModalContent, ModalBody } "@chakra-ui/react";

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";

import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/effect-coverflow";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import "swiper/css/navigation";

import { EffectCoverflow, Pagination, Navigation } from "swiper/modules";

import "./style.css";
```

```
const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();

  const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0);

  const sliderRef = useRef(null);

  const handleSlideChange = (swiper) => {
    setActiveSlide(swiper.realIndex);
  };

  const handleSlideButtonClick = (index) => {
    if (sliderRef.current) {
      sliderRef.current.swiper.slideTo(index);
      setActiveSlide(index);
    }
  };
```

```
<Modal isOpen={isOpen} size="9xl" onClose={onClose}>
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent>
          <ModalBody>
             <Swiper
                  effect={"coverflow"}
                  initialSlide='1'
                  spaceBetween={10}
                  grabCursor={false}
                  centeredSlides={true}
                  loop={true}
                  ref={sliderRef}
                  slidesPerView={"auto"}
                  coverflowEffect={{
                    rotate: 0,
                    stretch: 0,
                    depth: 100,
                    modifier: 0,
                  }}
                  pagination={{ el: ".swiper-pagination", clickable: true }}
                  navigation={{
                    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
                    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
                    clickable: true,
                  }}
                  modules={[EffectCoverflow, Pagination, Navigation]}
                  className="swiper_container"
                  onSlideChange={handleSlideChange}
                >
                  <SwiperSlide>
                    <SuccessScreen />
                  </SwiperSlide>
                  <SwiperSlide>
                    <IntroScreen />
                  </SwiperSlide>
                </Swiper>
            </ModalBody>
          </ModalContent>
</Modal>
```

style.css

```
  *,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.swiper_container {
  width: 120%;
  height: 52rem;
  padding: 0rem 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -999;
}

.swiper-slide {
  width: 33rem;
  height: 42rem;
  position: relative;
}
```

Tried setting the swiper-slide width to auto but it doesn't work at all. In fact the swiper disappears altogether